# Общий член для наследуемых классов

Tags: c#

Имеется абстрактный (базовый) класс (для примера):

```
public abstract class ClassBase
{
    protected static Logger logger = new Logger("logger_name");
}
```

И два потомка:

```
public class Class1 : ClassBase {}

public class Class2 : ClassBase {}
```

У потомков должен быть общий логгер. `Logger` реализует `IDisposable`. Как быть в таком случае? Мы же ведь не может выполнить `Dispose` на данном члене

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Никак. Статические поля не нужно `Dispose()`-ить, ведь они будут использованы другими экземплярами класса, создаваемыми после окончания работы `Dispose()` данного экземпляра.

---

Возможно, вам понадобится «вручную» закрыть логгер в конце работы программы, в тот момент, когда вы можете *гарантировать*, что экземпляров данного класса (и его потомков) больше нет. Более правильное решение — изменить дизайн логгера, чтобы он не требовал вызова `Dispose()` в конце работы.

Comment: Забавно, статический конструктор есть, а статического _деструктора_ нет?

Comment: @VladD спасибо. Изменил архитектуру, теперь не требует. Изначально планировал переписать, но думал, что может есть решение какое-нибудь...

Comment: @Grundy: Не-а, потому что а когда его вызывать?

Comment: @VladD в конце :-)

Comment: @Grundy: В конце _чего_?